# “Drove five hours” VS. “Drive for five Hours”

Tags: sentence-meaning

> - I **drove five** hours from Michigan to Chicago.

>

> - I **drove for five** hours from Michigan to Chicago.

Is there any meaningful difference between these two sentences?

Comment: They mean the same thing practically, but you cannot always omit **for**.   We would not say: *I looked for my car keys [] hours*.

Answer (score 0):

'I drove for five hours' is more formal.

'I drove five hours' has a slightly different connotation.

'for five hours' is an adverbial of time.

'five hours' appears to either represent an ellipsis omitting the preposition, or it feels like an object (noun) as in 'I drove a car' (a car is a noun phrase and is the object of the verb).